# create 'artificial' step 1 variable values in SAP BW

Tags: variables, abap, sap-bw

*start edit 2021.12.08*

to be more specific: what is the logic/syntax to hardcode input choices for the variable prompt (second row).

```
    WHEN 'z_step_1_variable'.
    ***MISSING KNOWLEDGE ABOUT ABAP***
    CLEAR L_S_RANGE.
    L_S_RANGE-OPT      = 'EQ'.
    L_S_RANGE-SIGN     = 'I'.
    L_S_RANGE-LOW = VALUE 1 ..... VALUE 5.
    APPEND L_S_RANGE TO E_T_RANGE.
```

*end edit*

I need to create a step 1 variable in SAP BW with ABAP which is **not** dependent on another characteristic but has 5 'artificial' values. I am not allowed to use a table or change infoprovider.

When a user opens a query he/she should have to choose one of the 5 predefined possible choices. I will then create step 2 variables which are dependent on user's selection.

Example string values for z_step_1_variable:

1. all structure elements
2. only str. elements 1 - 3
3. something 1
4. something 2
5. only str. element 1, 8 and 9

How can I create those 5 values? Up to know I only used step 1 variables which get the values from other characteristics. Is this a text variable and if so, how to hard code those 5 values?

thank you for your help/info
regards
p.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I created a variable, type characteristic value, processing by replacement path. However, this variable type requires a reference characteristic which is not available (I am not allowed to change anything at infoprovider level). 

That is why I came up with using a text variable, proccesing by customer-exit (single value).  In the past I always used variables which get their values from other characteristics. 

I do not understand how to create artificial values and make them available for user selection in variable z_step_1_variable.

br p.

Answer (score 0):

finally found a solution:

declare a new element of type string and then use the code above to get the values into the variable selection.

Until now I thought that a list or array have to be used for something like this...